# Making a graph of presence/absence

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to make a graphical representation of a dataset that looks like this, where the 1s and os, mean presence/absence:

```
f_list = ['feature_5','feature_3','feature_1','feature_4','feature_2','feature_6']
v = [[0,0,0,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=v, columns=f_list, index=range(6))
```

The best I have been able to come with is a barplot with the 'features' in 'x' and the sum of frequencies 'y':

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(6), columns=['Feature','sum'])
i=0
for f in f_list:
    new_df.loc[i,'Feature'] = f
    new_df.loc[i,'sum'] = df[f].sum()
    i += 1

import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.barplot(x="Feature", y="sum", data=new_df.sort_values(by='sum', axis=0, ascending=False))
```

But I want to be able to visualize the combinations of features.

I want to make something that would look like a heatmap or a confusion matrix, but the boxes would represent presence/absence only.
Like:

---

```
n_something   /feature_6/feature_2 / feature_4 / feature_1 / feature_3 / feature_5

  4               x                         
  2               x          x                      
  0               x          x         x                                
  3               x          x         x           x                    
  1               x          x         x           x         x          
  5               x          x         x           x         x          x
```

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Seaborn heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) will work (the easiest solution)

eg

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df, vmin=0, vmax=1, cbar=False, cmap="winter")
```

Play around with the [cmap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html) to get colours you like.

or alternatively, use [pandas dataframe styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html)